# Trusting self-signed SSL certificate for localhost (non-interactively)

Tags: docker, ssl, https, localhost, self-signed

I've set up HTTPS on localhost with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=America/New_York APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2 APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2 APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2.pid
COPY . /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
# install apache, php, ssl cert for localhost
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install apt-utils tzdata apache2 php libapache2-mod-php && \
  ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && \
  a2enmod ssl headers rewrite && \
  mv ./apache/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem && \
  mv ./apache/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key && \
  mv ./apache/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
EXPOSE 80 443
# start webserver
CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

Where `ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` and `ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` were generated with:

```
openssl req -x509 -out ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem -keyout ssl-cert-snakeoil.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

and `000-default.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
    ServerName localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I can access `https://localhost` in my browser, but it gives me a warning saying the certificate isn't trusted. I realize I could add the certificate to the browser's trust store, but my goal is to have other programs running in containers be able to access `https://localhost` on the host machine.

Other answers on StackExchange ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90607), [2](https://superuser.com/a/1189854), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17751)) say I should be able to do this by moving my `ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` from the container serving `https://localhost` to the one wanting to access it specifically to one of `/usr/share/ca-certificates/`, `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`, `/etc/ssl/certs/` (depending on the answer), and then running one of `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` or `update-ca-certificates --fresh` (again, depending on the answer).

So, I spin up a container with `docker run --network="host" -it ubuntu /bin/bash`, add the certs to the various locations and run the various commands but nothing will work. Running `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` seems promising because it actually prompts me saying "This package installs common CA (Certificate Authority) certificates in /usr/share/ca-certificates" then asks me to choose from a list of CAs which I [figured out](https://leehblue.com/add-self-signed-cert-curl/) I could add to with `echo /path/to/cert.crt >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf`. But this won't work.

I've done all these steps and every combination of them, but when I try `curl https://localhost` I still get `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`. Similarly, PHP complains when I try to run `<?php echo file_get_contents("https://localhost");` saying `PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /t.php on line 1`. What am I doing wrong? Furthermore, since I am trying to accomplish all this in a Dockerfile, I need a way of running `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` non-interactively (if that is indeed the correct command).

Comment: Have you tried adding in `php.ini` the directive `curl.cainfo = path/to/cacert.pem` and then running `file_get_contents` ?

Comment: That solution only works for PHP though, is there a way to get the cert trusted by all applications without their own trust store?

Comment: Unfortunately no, external clients must know(should have registered) the certificate authority. Best you can do is copy the CA from docker and register on the system you're trying to connect from, that way, all other browsers(except Firefox) will know about the CA and will accept the certs served by docker-apache

Comment: @darklightcode My ultimate goal is to have requests to `https://example.com` be redirected to some other destination (whether that be localhost, another IP, or a domain name) so I can write integration tests for example.com. Is there any global network configuration (perhaps `iptables`?) that will allow me to do this on just my machine?

Comment: i’m not sure i’m following ... but, you can point any domain to an ip address by editing your hosts file. Hosts file can be found on unix systems in ‘/etc/hosts’ or on windows in ‘windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts’

Comment: (1/2) Right, my `/etc/hosts` has an entry that says `127.0.0.1   example.com` so requests to `http://example.com` get redirected to localhost but requests to `https://example.com` get redirected to `https://127.0.0.1` which gives an SSL warning and since there's no way for `/etc/hosts` to change ports, there doesn't seem to be any way to have `https://example.com` get redirected to `http://127.0.0.1`.

Comment: (2/2) I was thinking a solution could be to use a domain name I have a Let's Encrypt cert for, changing `/etc/hosts` to say `mydomain.com   example.com` but `/etc/hosts` maps IPs to domains, not domains to domains, and I can't get an SSL cert for an IP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185870/discussion-between-darklightcode-and-tim).